# How to unhide launcher with mouse?

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I made launcher to autohide and now I can unhide it only with `Windows` key on keyboard.

Is there any way to unhide launcher with mouse?

Hovering mouse at the left of the screen has no effect.

Comment: You need to *slam* the mouse to the left. If it really doesn't work then 1. make sure you have NOT selected "left corner" (otherwise it only unhides if the mouse is slammed in a very small area around the top left corner, and 2. Adjust sensitivity up until it works comfortably.

Comment: In settings there's an option to tune launcher reveal sensitivity. Change that.